# Not space left on disk. Need Clean Up Help

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I have just installed crouton on a Chromebook to begin to work in Linux. I am struggling on freeing up some disk space for some reason and was looking for some help. Here is the output for

```
df -h:

Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /
/dev/root                  1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                   938M     0  938M   0% /dev
tmp                        940M  196K  939M   1% /tmp
run                        188M   20K  188M   1% /run
shmfs                      940M   17M  923M   2% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                  1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /home
/dev/mapper/encstateful    1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /var
media                      1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /media
/dev/sda1                  1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /usr/local
none                       940M     0  940M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                       938M     0  938M   0% /dev/pstore
/dev/sda1                  1.7G  1.7G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                   938M     0  938M   0% /dev
shmfs                      940M   17M  923M   2% /dev/shm
tmp                        940M  196K  939M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                      188M   20K  188M   1% /run
tmpfs                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
run                        940M  652K  939M   1% /var/host/dbus
run                        940M  652K  939M   1% /var/host/shill
run                        940M  652K  939M   1% /var/host/cras
/dev/mapper/encstateful    507M   51M  457M  10% /var/host/timezone
/dev/root                  1.2G  995M  210M  83% /lib/modules/3.8.11
run                        940M  652K  939M   1% /var/host/udev
media                      940M     0  940M   0% /var/host/media
/home/.shadow/793f9243fe474386e85d0cacc5fb62a098b05a94/vault  1.7G  1.7G     0 100%     /home/wes/Downloads
none                       940M     0  940M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I am really only looking to use this for some programming and not much else. If anyone sees/has any advice on how to clean some stuff up I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your package installation:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

You could use tools like:

```
Linux Disk Cleaner:
```

Download Link: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/linux-disk-cleaner/

```
Bleachbit:
```

Download Link: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bleachbit/

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way:

1. To do a clean up analize the available and occupied space.
2. Run a `du` command in `/` to detect the largest directories.
3. run this command to evaluate the disk usage and exclude the mount directory, sort        from largest file and pipe to less for readability

   ```
   sudo du . -ha --exclude=./mnt | sort -hr | less
   ```
4. manually delete some of the largest files based on dates, usage, etc
5. remove unused packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
6. clean up the cache if using graphic environments

   ```
   sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt
   ```
7. clean apt cache

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
8. clean up thumbnails cache in case of graphic environment

   ```
   rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
   ```

most of this information is based on experience some other is from [foss blog](https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/)